# Determine if a point lies inside a polygon defined in .kml file

Tags: javascript, google-maps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if a point is in polygon (maps)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066625/check-if-a-point-is-in-polygon-maps)

So I have a point defined by the user I need to check if that point lies within a polygon that has been defined inside a .kml file. The website has been written in c# using MVC3.

Using javascript I have a point (which a marker is displayed for) and at the moment a number of .kml layers are added to the map in the same region as the point. I would like to be able to just display 1 .kml layer, where the point lies inside the polygon defined in the .kml file.

I have found a number of example of people determining if a point is inside a polygon using javascript, such as this: https://github.com/tparkin/Google-Maps-Point-in-Polygon

The problem I have with using this is that I don't know how to create the polygon object using the .kml file. Is this even possible? Is doing this using javascript the best option?

Would I be better off doing this server side? At the moment the latitude and longitude of the point as well as the nearest .kml layers are returned via an ajax call would I better off implementing a ray casting algorithm on the server?

Edit: I should also mention that the polygons defined inside the .kml files contain on average around 300 points.